# Fake Glob operator (!!) not expanding directory paths

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I have a situation where in a Fake script I am trying to grab all the unit test dll's from a path using the Glob (!!) operator.

The issue is that on my machine the glob expansion doesn't work, on other similar Windows 10 machines at work, its fine and finds the dlls.

Below is an example:

```
let path = [function to generate path]
trace path [would look something like "c:\git\project\src\**\*UnitTest*"]
!! path.ToLower()
|> Seq.iter (fun file -> trace file ) [this would not output anything]
```

I've tried numerous things:

- uninstalling older versions of F#
- reinstalling the lastest version
- ensuring F# is in my Path

The versions of software I am using are:

- Fake v4.63.2
- Windows 10
- F#4.1

No errors or exceptions are thrown.
Whats the best way to trouble shoot if its an F# or a Fake issue?
How could I work out what version of F# Fake is using?

**Update**
I've reinstalled F# 4.1 and performed a test using `fsi.exe` with the following command:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 4.1
<snip>
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll";;
open Fake;;
!! "**\*UnitTests.dll" |> Seq.iter (fun x -> trace x);;
C:\git\project1\bin\Debug\project1.UnitTests.dll
C:\git\project2\bin\Debug\project2.UnitTests.dll

!! "**\*UnitTests.dll".ToLower() |> Seq.iter (fun x -> trace x);;
C:\git\project1\bin\Debug\project1.UnitTests.dll
C:\git\project2\bin\Debug\project2.UnitTests.dll
```

All the test dlls were found, both with and without the call to `ToLower()`.

When I remove the `ToLower()` from the script, it now works on my machine.

However, on other peoples machines removing `ToLower()` on the `path` causes them not to find any files.

So, is Fake using a different version of the `fsi.exe`?
I've opened a github issue to see if that sheds any light on it: https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1772

Comment: What's the behavior you're seeing? Is the path in your example a real path? Because if so, I think it needs backslash escaping

Comment: This string should *throw* because it contains invalid escape sequences

Comment: actually, good point - we use a function to determine the path. So I will change the example

Comment: You wrote "... on my machine the glob expansion doesn't work, on other similar machines at work its fine." This seems like a very important point to me. There's probably something different about your machine, and the script is probably fine. If one of the folders in your machine is missing, or named something else, then the glob is expanding to an empty list which is why nothing is printed. Could you double-check that every folder, from the root of C:, exists on your machine? And that there aren't some weird folder permissions preventing one folder from being read?

Comment: I missed a suttle detail in my example as I didn't have the code in front of me when doing the original post, see update in post.

Comment: If adding or removing `.ToLower()` is making a difference, then I'm wondering whether other people are using a case-insensitive filesystem. Are the other machines where this works also Windows 10 filesystems? Are they running Unix, where case matters? Too many details we don't know, so it's hard to guess what the answer might be.

Comment: All other systems are Windows 10

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've posted what the issue was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following script, I was able to reproduce the issue and work out that the issue was due to how Windows 10 handles the original casing of the `company` name, in the path.

I confirmed this by changing `company` name to `**` in the file path expression, the operator worked and found all the dlls.

I remember changing the capitalisation of the company name, from all caps to lower case. If I remove the `ToLower()` on the path, then the script works fine and finds all the dlls.

This hidden issue, combined with how [FAKE does a case sensitive search](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1772#issuecomment-363345870), doesn't help either.

*Powershell*

```
packages\FAKE\tools\FAKE.exe glob.test.fsx
```

*glob.test.fsx*

```
#r @"packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

let thePath = """C:\git\company/projectname/**/bin/Debug/*UnitTests.dll"""

sprintf "the path is %s" thePath |> trace 

!! thePath.ToLower() |> Seq.iter (fun f -> trace f)
```

I had a look at the process executing in **ProcMon** and did not see the original casing of the directory. The NTFS file system is still see this directory as its original casing (see comments below).

I re-image my machine every few months, so this will disappear soon but it was good to understand what was going on.

Thanks to all those that helped narrow the issue down.

Comment: There's no "somewhere". NTFS preserves the filename's case even though it doesn't use case-sensitive matching. You *shouldn't* have to use `ToLower()` at all. If you do, it means there's a bug in the  glob operator's code. NTFS offers only simple pattern matching. The Glob operator filters files using string comparisons. It looks like some of them are case sensitive

Comment: BTW Linux file systems are case-sensitive which means `Company` and `company` are different and you can even have both folders under the same root. Instead of using `ToLower()` you should probably make sure the casing is correct in all cases. `ToLower()` won't help if the *path* name is uppercase for example.

Comment: Finally, the Glob operator *does* perform a [case-sensitive match](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/Fake.Core.Globbing/Globbing.fs#L132).

Answer (score 2):

In F# as in all .NET languages, the backslash is used for escape sequences in strings.

You need to escape the backslash or use a verbatim string, eg :

```
let path = "c:\\git\\project\\src\\**\\*UnitTest*"
```

or

```
let path = @"c:\git\project\src\**\*UnitTest*"
```

Fake can work with forward slashes as well :

```
let path = "c:/git/project/src/**/*UnitTest*"
```

You'll have to use forward slashes anyway if you want your build script to run on Linux.

An even better option is to use *relative* paths. Your build script most likely is stored in your project folder. You can write

```
let path = "src/**/*UnitTest*"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've posted what the issue was.